# Keyczar implementation in Android sample

Tags: android, keyczar

I am looking to secure my data using Keyczar and I came across [android-keyczar-demo](https://github.com/kruton/android-keyczar-demo) but the demo seems to be unavailable. Is anyone aware of a demo?

I went through the pdf from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwibl63D5uXLAhXFcI4KHeRaBY8QFggrMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkeyczar.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Fkeyczar05b.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHUX0HvjHPkKWj-RlKl-Zm8ksJK5A&sig2=QCj2vmROXKKq30Tr1wufyw&bvm=bv.117868183,d.c2E) as well - however I am struggling with setting location with KeyczarTool etc. Not sure how this is implemented in Android. Any help is appreciated.